# How do I check in javascript if the html page was valid?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

Is there a way to query the browser if the page that loaded the javascript was valid, at least as far as the browser is concerned? Obviously the browser loads this page and not so much as validates it, but rather interprets it for display. Is there a way to query the list of errors and warnings that the browser generated when processing the html?

This would be a neat way to generate warning in selenium for syntax of the page.

Comment: You can in Opera (using selenium you can in every browser). Use the w3c web [verifier](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: you can use web developer extension, available in all major browsers. (don't know about IE as I never use it)

Comment: The browser generally won't generate a list of errors for HTML, but you can use the W3C soap client to validate a document, but that's not accessible from javascript (same origin policy), but would require a call from the server that passes the URL or the markup of the page to be validated, and it's slow and really pointless in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of sheer necessity browsers do not actually validate html in any way and only parse it.
If you wish to know if the browser had any issue parsing it, you can take a stringified version of the original html, and compare it to a stringified version of the HTML after the browser has parsed it.
If the browser encountered any parsing issues (no matter how small), it will have edited your HTML source in order to make the DOM tree generate properly.
Note though that even this method is not foolproof, because the browser will only fix problems it can understand, for example, using an invalid html tag has no effect as far as the browser is concerned when it comes to parsing your html.

Answer (score 0):

You could AJAX in the W3C validator and interpret the results. Something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var yourURL = window.location.href;
    var urlencode = encodeURIComponent(yourURL);

    $('#your-results-container').load('http://validator.w3.org/check?uri='+urlencode+' #results');
});`
```

This would take your current URL, urlencode it, run it through the W3C validator and load the results div of that page into your div "your-results-container". You could then parse through it and do whatever you wanted with IDs or classes of errors or warnings.